# How to solve failed to fetch error in swagger?

Tags: swagger-ui

I wrote a swagger documentation for a set of APIs that I have built. But in the swagger's server response, it throws an error:

```
Code:
Undocumented

Details:
Failed to fetch.

Possible Reasons:
CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

This is my swagger spec:

```
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost"
paths:
  /registerCustomer:
```

I'm using my APIs in localhost. Is that the reason for this failure? (My APIs are working successfully in localhost though)

Comment: What's the full error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I have been using swagger in VS Code extension. Not on browser